# Center aligned UITextfield changes its placeholder towards left when tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have center aligned UITextfields in tableview cells. 
Whenever, user taps on any textfield, its placeholder slightly move towards left.
I have attached screenshots as well. Please help me.

[image: In first picture, fusion id is moved towards left as its selected.]

[image: In second picture, password is moved towards left as its selected.]

Comment: Can you post your code? Or have you created this in a storyboard/xib?

Comment: @RhuariGlen in storyboard

Comment: Please confirm to you have first character should not be white space (with placeholder) may be it's create a this issue.

Comment: @Tubelight its not space

Answer (score 3):

I subclassed UITextField like this:

```
class MyTextField : UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        if let placeholderText = self.placeholder {

            let centeredParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            centeredParagraphStyle.alignment = .center
            let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: centeredParagraphStyle])
            self.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Interface Builder set the class of the UITextField to **MyTextField**

[image: Set the Custom Class of the IB Object]

Here are some images of MyTextField's behaviour compared to UITextField

[image: Two placeholders behaving differently]
[image: normal carat aligns to beginning of Placeholder which is also beginning UITexField]
[image: centered carat aligns only to beginning of placeholder]
[image: normal text entry aligns to beginning of UITextField]
[image: "centred" text entry also aligns to beginning of MyTextField]

This may not be the full behaviour you want but the placeholder does not "jump around" and it is possible to extend this kind of technique to overcome other behaviours if desired.

Comment: Moreover, your code is not compiling in swift 3. Its giving error on
 [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: centeredParagraphStyle]

Comment: You could have said at the outset, "hey everyone I need a swift 3 solution for this" OR you could have tagged the question Swift3 OR you could fix the compiler error you get and post the solution here.....

Comment: Yes. I compiled your code for Swift 3.0 but it didn't work